# ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression pgadmin

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a small problem in my sql code, more specifically in a function that is executed by a trigger.

I tried to use only 1 select in my if (doing different if's for each query), but the error remains the same. Other functions I've done use the same type of query and do not return this problem.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TIME_UPDATE() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE IDPART INT;
DECLARE VENC INT;
DECLARE PERD INT;
BEGIN

SELECT INTO IDPART OLD.IDPARTIDAS FROM PARTIDAS WHERE OLD.IDPARTIDAS = NEW.IDPARTIDAS;
SELECT INTO VENC OLD.VENCEDOR FROM PARTIDAS WHERE OLD.IDPARTIDAS = NEW.IDPARTIDAS;
SELECT INTO PERD OLD.PERDEDOR FROM PARTIDAS WHERE OLD.IDPARTIDAS = NEW.IDPARTIDAS;

IF((VENC != (SELECT NEW.VENCEDOR FROM PARTIDAS WHERE IDPART = NEW.IDPARTIDAS))
AND (VENC = (SELECT NEW.PERDEDOR FROM PARTIDAS WHERE IDPART = NEW.IDPARTIDAS)))
THEN
    UPDATE TIME SET OLD.VITORIAS = COALESCE(VITORIAS, 0) - 1, PONTUACAO = COALESCE(PONTUACAO, 0) - 5
    WHERE IDTIME = VENC;
    UPDATE TIME SET DERROTAS = COALESCE(DERROTAS, 0) + 1, PONTUACAO = COALESCE(PONTUACAO, 0) - 2
    WHERE IDTIME = VENC; 
END IF;

IF((PERD != (SELECT NEW.PERDEDOR FROM PARTIDAS WHERE IDPART = NEW.IDPARTIDAS))
AND (PERD = (SELECT NEW.VENCEDOR FROM PARTIDAS WHERE IDPART = NEW.IDPARTIDAS)))
THEN
    UPDATE TIME SET OLD.VITORIAS = COALESCE(VITORIAS, 0) + 1, PONTUACAO = COALESCE(PONTUACAO, 0) + 5
    WHERE IDTIME = PERD;
    UPDATE TIME SET DERROTAS = COALESCE(DERROTAS, 0) - 1, PONTUACAO = COALESCE(PONTUACAO, 0) + 2
    WHERE IDTIME = PERD;
END IF;

    UPDATE TIME SET OLD.VITORIAS = COALESCE(VITORIAS, 0) - 1, PONTUACAO = COALESCE(PONTUACAO, 0) - 5
    WHERE IDTIME = VENC;
    UPDATE TIME SET OLD.VITORIAS = COALESCE(DERROTAS, 0) - 1, PONTUACAO = COALESCE(PONTUACAO, 0) + 2
    WHERE IDTIME = PERD;
RETURN NEW;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

CREATE TRIGGER ATUALIZAR_PARTIDA AFTER UPDATE ON PARTIDAS FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE TIME_UPDATE();
```

The error:

> ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression---------------CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT ((VENC != (SELECT NEW.VENCEDOR FROM PARTIDAS
>   WHERE IDPART = NEW.IDPARTIDAS)) AND 
>                (VENC = (SELECT NEW.PERDEDOR FROM PARTIDAS WHERE IDPART = NEW.IDPARTIDAS)))"--------------------
>   PL/pgSQL function time_update() line 11 at IF-----------------------------------------------------------
>   SQL state: 21000

Comment: the three `select into` statements at the beginning make no sense at all (I am surprised that that syntax even compiles). There is no need to store column values of the `new` or `old` records into a variable. As far as I can tell, you need none of those SELECT statements and e.g. the first `IF` can be simplified to `if (new.vencedor <> old.vencedor) then...`

Comment: Actually the IF statements make no sense at all to begin with. If I remove the noise from the select statements it boils down to `if (venc != new.vencedor and venc = new.vencedor)` which will  never be true.

Comment: The reference to `OLD.VITORIAS` as a column of the `time` table is also invalid. And the final UPDATEs overwrite whatever you did in the IF blocks - your whole trigger does not make any sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your whole trigger code is way to complicated and wrong in some places.

1. To assign a variable from a select statement you need to use `select column_name into variable from ...` **not** `select into variable ...`
2. There is no need to "copy" the values of the new or old records using a select statement to begin with. Actually there is no need to copy those values at all.
3. If you want to reference a column from the `new` or `old` record you don't need a select statement.
4. You don't need two update statements to update two columns, this can be done with a single statement.
5. You can't use columns from the `old` record as the target column for an UPDATE statement, `SET OLD.VITORIAS = ...` is invalid and I am surprised that that even compiles. I assume you meant to write `set vitorias = ....`
6. The updates to the `vitorias` column in the IF statements are overwritten with the unconditional updates after the two IF blocks. And in case of the last UPDATE with a completely different value as well.

Removing all the wrong or unnecessary code, I think you are looking for this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TIME_UPDATE() 
RETURNS TRIGGER 
AS 
$$
DECLARE 
  VENC INT;
  PERD INT;
BEGIN
    -- this is useless. All references to "venc" or "perd" can 
    -- directly be replaced with a reference to the old record.
    venc := old.vencedor;
    perd := old.perdedor;

    IF (new.vencedor <> old.vencedor)
    THEN
        UPDATE time 
            SET vitorias = coalesce(vitorias, 0) - 1, pontuacao = coalesce(pontuacao, 0) - 5,
                derrotas = coalesce(derrotas, 0) + 1, pontuacao = coalesce(pontuacao, 0) - 2
        WHERE idtime = venc; 
    END IF;

    IF (new.perdedor <> old.perdedor) 
    THEN
        UPDATE time 
            SET vitorias = coalesce(vitorias, 0) + 1, pontuacao = coalesce(pontuacao, 0) + 5,
                derrotas = coalesce(derrotas, 0) - 1, pontuacao = coalesce(pontuacao, 0) + 2
        WHERE idtime = perd;
    END IF;

    -- this overwrites the change done in the first IF block with the same value
    UPDATE TIME 
       SET vitorias = coalesce(vitorias, 0) - 1, pontuacao = coalesce(pontuacao, 0) - 5
    WHERE IDTIME = venc;

    -- this overwrites the change done in the second IF block with a different(!) value
    UPDATE TIME 
        SET vitorias = coalesce(derrotas, 0) - 1, pontuacao = coalesce(pontuacao, 0) + 2
    WHERE idtime = perd;

    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Comment: Hmm, I get it. I think I should have stopped and analyzed my code better. I'll try to fix it according to what you told me, if I can, I'll come back to comment on what I've changed. Thanks for the answer. :)

Comment: I got it! I made the corrections to the errors that you had alerted me and I spent a good time analyzing the rest of the code. I have other triggers that complement this, but they are correct and finally all of them perform their functions.

Comment: I'm sorry if I did not explain it right, especially the name of the tables that are in my language (Portuguese). What I'm doing is a database for a CS: GO championship system. It has a table of teams and matches. For each match is inserted, changed or deleted, it is necessary to update in the times table the score, the classification, the number of defeats and victories.

Comment: This trigger was performing this function at the time of a match's update. I'll show you how the trigger is after the fix.

Comment: `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TIME_UPDATE() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN

IF(((SELECT OLD.VENCEDOR FROM PARTIDAS WHERE IDPARTIDAS = NEW.IDPARTIDAS) != 
 (NEW.VENCEDOR)) AND 
    ((SELECT OLD.VENCEDOR FROM PARTIDAS WHERE IDPARTIDAS = NEW.IDPARTIDAS) = 
 (NEW.PERDEDOR)))
THEN
 UPDATE TIME SET VITORIAS = COALESCE(VITORIAS, 0) - 1, PONTUACAO = COALESCE(PONTUACAO, 0) - 7,
 DERROTAS = COALESCE(DERROTAS, 0) + 1
 WHERE IDTIME = OLD.VENCEDOR;`

Comment: `ELSIF (((SELECT OLD.PERDEDOR FROM PARTIDAS WHERE IDPARTIDAS = NEW.IDPARTIDAS) != 
  (NEW.PERDEDOR)) AND 
    ((SELECT OLD.PERDEDOR FROM PARTIDAS WHERE IDPARTIDAS = NEW.IDPARTIDAS) = 
     (NEW.VENCEDOR)))
   THEN
 UPDATE TIME SET VITORIAS = COALESCE(VITORIAS, 0) + 1, PONTUACAO = COALESCE(OPONTUACAO, 0) + 7,
 DERROTAS = COALESCE(DERROTAS, 0) - 1
 WHERE IDTIME = OLD.PERDEDOR;

ELSE 
 `

Comment: `UPDATE TIME SET VITORIAS = COALESCE(VITORIAS, 0) - 1, PONTUACAO = COALESCE(PONTUACAO, 0) - 5
 WHERE IDTIME = OLD.VENCEDOR;
 UPDATE TIME SET DERROTAS = COALESCE(DERROTAS, 0) - 1, PONTUACAO = COALESCE(PONTUACAO, 0) + 2
 WHERE IDTIME = OLD.PERDEDOR;
END IF;
  
RETURN NEW;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

CREATE TRIGGER ATUALIZAR_PARTIDA BEFORE UPDATE ON PARTIDAS FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE TIME_UPDATE();`

Answer (score 0):

This comparison:

```
VENC != (SELECT NEW.VENCEDOR FROM PARTIDAS WHERE IDPART = NEW.IDPARTIDAS
```

And the other ones similar to this one, must return a single record.
You can run manually all of these queries until you find that/those one/s returning more than one record.